# User control allow drop

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, drag-and-drop, sharpdevelop

I have a `UserControl` which looks like `WPF's XAML` editor. I want to drag treenodes in it and do stuff. The drag system is working for the treeview part. But I can't seem to make the drop part work in my custom control. (The control is builded using `sharpdevelop` libraries).

I set my custom control's `AllowDrop` properties to `True`. I added this to my control :

```
this.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.XmlEditControl_DragDrop)

private void XmlEditControl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("I dropped");
}
```

But I never see the messagebox. Am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to change the `DragDropEffects` of the `DragEventArgs` when the `DragEnter` event is fired first to complete the drag-and-drop operation. Thus, the `DragDrop` event would fire

**Example**

```
this.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.XmlEditControl_DragEnter);
this.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.XmlEditControl_DragDrop);

private void XmlEditControl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
}
private void XmlEditControl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("I dropped");
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Does not work. I still see the "Can't drop here" sign so I'm not allowed to drop in the control at all, the effect doesnt fire and my message box either.:(

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Not really sure what the problem might be. Did you make sure that other events fire properly? If so, may you please try to show the `MessageBox` under the `DragOver` event? :)

Comment: Does the same thing. God this is annoying since it should work. 0_o

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Does other events fire properly, including `Load` of course? There might be something wrong with your control, are you sure that `AllowDrop` is set to `True`? Did you try creating another user control and checking if `DragDrop` is firing?

Comment: Yes. The problem is the design (inspired by sharpdevelop) where controls and forms and classes are created by reflexion and stuff. This is where I pay the price of this kind of design

Comment: I figured it out. I had to go to the parent where XmlEditor is docked. And instead of typing only this.Drag I had to type xmlEditor.TextArea.ActiveArea.Drag........ ouch but now it works thanks. If you ever want to put this in your answer i'll accept it

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I'm glad you had your issue resolved. Have a nice day :)